# Physics engine recommendation which can simulate pool game correctly?

Tags: physics

I'm making a pool-game like game. This game requires correct (or very accurate) reflective bounces.
I tried *Box2D* and *Bullet Physics*, but they both have this problem.

[image: Illustration]

If there is a wall on top of this image, red line is expected course of a real ball in a pool-game. But the engines often shows green line course. Especially,

1. This happens after a slowly moving ball hits the wall.
2. Sometimes a rapidly moving ball get slower suddenly.

I'm finding a physics engine which can simulate pool-game accurately as much as possible without these problems. Can I get some recommendations? Now I'm digging *Newton Game Dynamics*, but I am not sure the engine will show what I want. I'm considering the *PhysX* engine as a next trial, and have to make my own if nothing works. But it's obvious it'll take very long time, so I wish I won't do that.
I'll be very appreciated if you save my time. And of course, solution with Box2D / Bullet Physics are also welcomed.

I am working with C/C++/Objective+C on iOS.

---

I attach my configuration with Box2D.

## Walls

- static box shape
- linear/angular damping = 0.1
- restitution = 1.0
- friction = 100
- density = 10
- bullet = false
- fixed rotation = false
- inertial scale = 1.0

## Balls

- dynamic sphere shape
- linear/angular damping = 0.1
- restitution = 1.0
- friction = 100
- density = 20
- bullet = true
- fixed rotation = false
- inertial scale = 1.0

Comment: chances are that the engine is not wrong, but you've not set a property or doing it wrong somehow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an algorithm for a pool game?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7862/is-there-an-algorithm-for-a-pool-game)

Comment: I tested with density 1 and friction 0.0 ~ 0.1, it keeps sticking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several solutions.

1. For Box2D, set `b2_velocityThreshold` in `b2Settings.h` file. In my case, I set it to `0.0f` and it worked! Mass, friction, damping were NOT problem.
   Check this discussion thread for more details.
   http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6906&p=30782#p30782
2. Using other physics engine.
   *Newton Game Dynamics* configured performing this correctly by default.
   However using Newton dynamics in iOS is possible but it's somewhat harder than others. I used several days configuring it for iOS.

I'm also asking on BulletPhysics forums. I'll update this when I got a solution.

-- (edit) --

There are some threshold attributes in Bullet, however I couldn't find exactly same thing with `b2_velocityThreshold`.

This looks similar, but didn't work well.

```
btRigidBody->setContactProcessingThreshold(0.0f)
```

Answer (score 6):

Box2D will do what you want but you have to set the restitution (bounce) constants for the wall and ball fixtures. For a pool game you probably want to start with perfect restitution and high friction but linear and angular damping, and tweak from there.

Comment: I tried many configurations over few days, but it still happens. Can I get one good example...?

Comment: Your density and friction values seem very large, for Box2D.

Answer (score 4):

Physics engines have a bounce threshold. I don't know how to do it in either of those engines, but the threshold being set too high will cause it to ignore impacts under a certain velocity. Lower the bounce threshold and it will bounce at lower speeds.

I know you asked for a different physics engine, but all physics engines I know of use bounce thresholds to keep objects from jittering when they're sitting on top of each other. So suggesting a good physics engine will be counterproductive as any good physics engine will have this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and for me the solution was providing perfect restitution.

So for me that is sqrt of 0.5 for all objects. Because sqrt(r1*r1 + r2*r2) == 1 in perfect situation.